# VSE shortening clips when rendering

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have blender set at 24fps, and several input video files at 24fps. I add them into Blender, and preview them and they play fine. After rendering the project however, each clip is shortened by a small amount (as if sped down) and the last couple of frames of each clip is black.

Why would these clips be shortened by rendering? They are the same fps as the Blender settings (100% sure. 24fps). If I play these clips in a video player they are the right length, but when I render them in Blender they are sped up. (leaving black screen in between each clip)

Thanks for the help

edit:
[image]

in this first picture the clip has just been added to the VSE. The clip is 24fps and Blender is 24fps. The last frame (1422) is the last image of the clip. All good here.

[image]

in this second picture is after rendering. The last image of the clip is now at frame 1411. The 11 frames after that are now black. When I play the first clip in a video player it is the appropriate length. When I play the second clip it is sped up, and the remainder of the clip is the default black screen.

I have no idea why this is happening

Comment: How did you arrange them in the VSE? Can you provide a screenshot? Are they touching each other?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am uploading pictures to clarify what I mean now